# Tomcat: unpacked WAR vs packed WAR in docBase

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Tomcat can use both types - or directly from *app.war* file with:

```
    <Host
      ...
      unpackWARs="false"
      autoDeploy="false"
      deployOnStartup="false">

      <Context
        path=""
        docBase="app.war"
      />
```

Or - with *directory*, created from unpacked WAR-file:

```
    <Host
      ...
      unpackWARs="true"
      autoDeploy="true"
      deployOnStartup="false">

      <Context
        path=""
        docBase="app"
      />
```

Question is - what is difference?

As I understand: during startup - Tomcat load content of *directory* OR *war-file* in to memory - and then works with it directly from RAM. So - there must not  be any difference in performance. Is it correct? Is there any any other deatils?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussed previously at other places such as [this one](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/0733pk7gqk/unpackwars-pros-and-cons).

In essence

- war file gets unpacked anyway, but in a work directory rather than in webapps.
- on windows you might have issues w/ files being locked by OS and not deletable, although there is known workaround for it.
- root path will not be same so if your app is writing something to file system, you might run into issues.

HTH,
Jan